# How are holomorphic and real-analytic Eisenstein series related?

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms

The holomorphic Eisenstein series can be given as
$$G_{2k}(z)=\sum_{(c,d)\in{\bf Z}^2\backslash(0,0)}\frac{1}{(cz+d)^{2k}}$$
while the real-analytic Eisenstein series is
$$E(z,s)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{(c,d)=1}\frac{y^s}{|cz+d|^{2s}}$$
satisfying the relation
$$2\zeta(2s)E(s,z)=\sum_{(c,d)\in{\bf Z}^2\backslash(0,0)}\frac{\text{Im}(z)^s}{|cz+d|^{2s}}.$$
They look to be very similar, but have different analytic behaviours. I haven't found a discussions on how they are related, so I'm hoping to find some answers.